# SimpleAmqpClient Channel::basicConsume() ,how to fetch all the messages from the RabbitMQ

Tags: c++, rabbitmq

This one is a very basic question ,I'll split this one in two parts

Use case : 
I'm writing a c++ application which needs to communicate to RabbitMQ running on server. Currently I'm able to publish messages on the queue and and consume message from the queue (only one message consumed if n messages were in the queue).

As I can read from the description of basicConsume() method 
"Starts consuming Basic messages on a queue
 Subscribes as a consumer to a queue, so all future messages on a queue
 will be Basic.Delivered"

So whenever I do a basicConsume() on my queue all my messages are delivered to me (on the server my queue is empty),

I'm doing something like

```
#include <SimpleAmqpClient/SimpleAmqpClient.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
using namespace AmqpClient;


int main()
{
    Channel::ptr_t connection = Channel::Create("ip",5672,usename,password);

    const std::string body("Test Message3");
    BasicMessage::ptr_t out_message = BasicMessage::Create(body);
//code to publish , works fine 
//connection->BasicPublish("exchange", "key",BasicMessage::Create("Message1"));

//BasicConsume say we have 5 messages in my queue
string consumer_tag=connection->BasicConsume("queue","");

Envelope::ptr_t envelope = connection->BasicConsumeMessage(consumer_tag);
        connection->BasicAck(envelope->GetDeliveryInfo());
        BasicMessage::ptr_t bodyBasicMessage=envelope->Message();
        string messageBody=bodyBasicMessage->Body();
        cout<<"message  body : "<<messageBody<<endl;
}
```

I'm able to only read the very first message in the queue.

Question:

1. how can I make a C++ consumer that continuously listen to my queue and whenever there is a message application consumes it(Hosting a c++ application / using threads / using infinite loop ) I don't have any experience with threads or hosting a c++ application (currently I'm just limited to executables ) so any suggested reads are most welcomed.
2. How do I read rest 4 messages which are getting dropped.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou @Luke for the response.
I resolved my issue of dropping messages by doing following
BasicConsume with noAck set to false -> basicConsumeMessage inside an infinite loop followed by a basicAck() 
by doing this my application wait to consume from the queue ( doesn't break when there is no message in queue ) and queue dont sent me the next message till it receive ACK for the first one.

now I'm planning to make it as a daemon so closing the terminal wont affect the execution.

any other suggestions are most welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following issue, you must consume every message via a call to `BasicConsumeMessage` -
https://github.com/alanxz/SimpleAmqpClient/issues/162

This library does not support asynchronous callbacks.